# How to stop ART from creating /OAT/..odex for third party application in android 8.0(Oreo)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Currently ART is creating the oat folder for every application whenever I am starting that application at runtime. This oat folder contains .odex and .vdex file:
e.g.

```
app/sample.apk
app/oat

app/oat/instruction_set/sample.odex
app/oat/instruction_set/sample.vdex
```

How can I stop this oat folder creation in Android Oreo?

Comment: That is part of the Operating System: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/jit-compiler

Comment: can't we disable it?

Comment: Perhaps in a Custom ROM: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure note the Makefile options.

Comment: I tried those makefile options from the same link, but none of them worked.

Comment: Then you should explain in detail what you are doing and how you are testing. I'm not sure why you want to disable a major feature of the platform.

Comment: As per the requirement, we don't want oat folder where apk is present.

Comment: For third party apps only we want to disable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204026/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-sandip-pawar).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
```